# remove all characters of a string after 5th character?

Tags: javascript

I need to remove all characters of a string after 5th character, 
for example

my string is

```
P-CI-7-C-71
```

and the output should be like

```
P-CI-
```

Comment: 'P-CI-7-C-71'.substring(0,5);

Comment: `'P-CI-7-C-71'.replace(/^(.{5}).*$/,'$1');` too, but *substring* is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)**

```
alert("P-CI-7-C-71".substring(0, 5));
```

So you can use it like

```
var str='P-CI-7-C-71'.substring(0, 5);
```

You can also use **[substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)**, that will work the same in this case but remember they work differently so they are not generally interchangeable

```
var str='P-CI-7-C-71'.substr(0, 5);
```

Difference can be noticed in the prototype

> str.substring(indexStart[, indexEnd])

VS

> str.substr(start[, length])

Answer (score 1):

Extracting String Parts

There are 3 methods for extracting a part of a string:

```
slice(start, end)
substring(start, end)
substr(start, length)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

> The `substring()` method returns a subset of a string between one index and another, or through the end of the string.

```js
document.write('P-CI-7-C-71'.substring(0, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
alert('P-CI-7-C-71'.substring(0,5));
```

```js
var str = 'P-CI-7-C-71';
var res = str.slice(0,5);
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Can use substring function in the JS

> the Substring(StringName,StartPosition, End Position);